# Creating a searchable PDF from one already existing PDF and text (with coordinates)

Tags: pdf, text, pdf-generation, ocr, pdfkit

**My Situation:**

- I have an existing PDF with only images
- I have a preprocessed OCR with all text identified and their respective coordinates
- An application running in C#
- I can use other programming languages if needed

**My Question:**

-> Do you know a way to create a searchable PDF using those existing resources (Images and Text with their coordinates) <-

I'm doing a lot of research but most of the results I get only show how to create a searchable PDF using some library (iText, PDF Sharp, etc.) that uses their built-in OCR engine, that is not my case, I already have the text and coordinates.

Thank you for any help and thought you can provide me.

Comment: Alternatively you can draw the text invisibly over the image. Any decent PDF library should allow you to draw text at arbitrary positions on existing PDFs. In particular the two libraries you mentioned, iText and PdfSharp do.

Comment: You can find an example for drawing the text using the character coordinates in a forum post [here](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t18073-). After drawing the text over the image, a PDF output is generated using the DocumentWriter class from the LEADTOOLS toolkit. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)